# How to display dynamic response from google search results?

Tags: node.js, google-search, google-search-api, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to program API.AI to display  search results from Google, using Actions on Google in the form of cards using webhook fulfillment service.
I have deployed demo application "factsaboutgoogle", but it gives out static response.
I want to write index.js code that could return dynamic response using google search engine.

Can anyone help we with the code?

This is the code i am using right now:

```
process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const App = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiApp;


// [START YourAction]
exports.videoplayer = (request, response) => {
  const app = new App({request, response});
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


  // Fulfill action business logic
  function responseHandler (app) {


    var querystring = require('querystring');
    var https = require('https');


    var host = 'https : //www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=*****';
    var apiKey = '*****';
    var sessionId = null;
    var deckId = '';


    function performRequest(endpoint, method, data, success) {
      var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
      var headers = {};

      if (method == 'GET') {
        endpoint += '?' + querystring.stringify(data);
      }
      else {
        headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': dataString.length
        };
      }
      var options = {
        host: host,
        path: endpoint,
        method: method,
        headers: headers
      };


      var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        var responseString = '';
        res.on('data', function(data) {
          responseString += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
          console.log(responseString);
          var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
          success(responseObject);
        });
      });

      req.write(dataString);
      req.end();
    }
  }

  function basicCard (app) {
    app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
    // Create a basic card and add it to the rich response

    .addSimpleResponse('')
    .addBasicCard(app.buildBasicCard(dataString)
      .setTitle('your query result')
      .addButton('Read more')
      .setImage('https://example.google.com/42.png', 'Image alternate text')
    ));
  }

  const actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set('videoplayer', responseHandler);

  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
};
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do the search? Or how to turn the search results into the cards? Good practice on StackOverflow is to show what you've done so far and explain what doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Both. i am trying to display the search results in form of cards in the chatbot.

Comment: Can you show the code you currently have that isn't working and describe what you're getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To start with Create a Google Custom search engine on the Google API Dashboard:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

You have to query Google using rest api and get results.

I have drafted the code as per your request using the rest api [code here](https://rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script):

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var https = require('https');

var host = 'https : //www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=<The word you 
want to search>';
var apiKey = '*****';
var sessionId = null;
var deckId = '';

function performRequest(endpoint, method, data, success) {
 var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
 var headers = {};

 if (method == 'GET') {
  endpoint += '?' + querystring.stringify(data);
 }
 else {
  headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Content-Length': dataString.length
 };
}
var options = {
host: host,
path: endpoint,
method: method,
headers: headers
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
res.setEncoding('utf-8');

 var responseString = '';

  res.on('data', function(data) {
  responseString += data;
 });

 res.on('end', function() {
 console.log(responseString);
 var responseObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
 success(responseObject);
 });
});

 req.write(dataString);
 req.end();
}
```

Comment: I made some changes to the code using https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-webhook-template-nodejs/blob/master/index.js 
Still it is not returning any search value.

Comment: I presume you have created the custom search and When you execute you are getting an error or you are not getting results at all.In both cases first I would suggest executing and testing the rest API outside the code. To test visit the below url in browser                                                     
`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
 key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=<The word you 
want to search>`

Comment: cx=017576662512468239146 has to be replaced by your custom search id

Comment: I have posted the code in the answer please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with the code.

1. Nowhere in your code are you *calling* `performRequest()` to actually do the search, so you're not getting results back, and aren't adding them to any cards. You'll need to include a `success` parameter, which is the function that can handle the JSON results back (the `responseObject`).
2. I don't see any function which would look like a good candidate for that `success` function. Your `basicCard()` function, as you note, just puts static information there. You would need to modify this to loop over the results from `responseObject` and use it to build the cards you want. (Probably one card per result, so you would call `addBasicCard()` multiple times. You can call it in a loop and add it on to the rich response you're building.)
3. You shouldn't have an empty simple response. This would be a good place to say "Here are your query results", so something like `.addSimpleResponse('Here are your results")` would be best in that line.